# Displaying string value in Doctrine 1.2 oneToMany relationship

Tags: symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

```
city
  columns
  id
  name
  province_id
Relation
  Province
  one to many
Province
  columns 
  id
  province_name
```

I want to display the string value instead of foreign id.So far

```
<?php foreach($results as $r): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['province_id']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

displays

```
 name   province
 Kansas 1(province_id)
```

I want instead

```
 name    province
 KANSAS  SOUTH PROVINCE
```

in tableClass

```
public function SearchCity($name)
{
    return $this->createQuery('c')
    ->andWhere('c.name like ?', '%'.$name.'%')
    ->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

my problem is I want to echo province_name instead of province_id

Any Idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your tableClass query like this

```
public function SearchCity($name)
{
   return $this->createQuery('c')
    ->select('c.*')
    ->innerJoin('c.Province p')
    ->addSelect('p.name as provincename')
    ->andWhere('c.name like ?', '%'.$name.'%')
    ->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

And now you can easily display string values instead of foreign ids

```
<td><?php echo $r['name'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $r['provincename'] ?></td>
```